# Mounting local directory in docker container on Windows fails silently

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to mount a local windows directory as a volume in a docker container, but after mounting it I cannot see any of my local files in the container. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

First I run:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/myuser/documents/development:/home image/name`
```

It executes without any error message. Then I run:

```
docker run image/name ls /home
```

And the files from inside C:/Users/myuser/Documents/development are not displayed. Am I making some wrong assumptions about how this should work? Is there an error in my commands?

I've also discovered that if I use the `-it` flags the volume mounts successfully, but upon exiting the docker container the I see the volume is no longer mounted. This works: `docker run -it -v /c/Users/myuser/documents/development:/home image/name`

Here are the last few lines from my docker.log:

```
time="2016-06-20T19:32:41.843405613Z" level=debug msg="event unhandled: type:\"start-container\" id:\"210bdd5a0a0b13491f388b001bcb7a1add12a65706be7831f82c94d74424025d\" timestamp:1466451161 " 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:41.844850367Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.23/containers/210bdd5a0a0b13491f388b001bcb7a1add12a65706be7831f82c94d74424025d/resize?h=24&w=111" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42Z" level=debug msg="containerd: process exited" id=210bdd5a0a0b13491f388b001bcb7a1add12a65706be7831f82c94d74424025d pid=init status=0 systemPid=1773 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.034419978Z" level=debug msg="received containerd event: &types.Event{Type:\"exit\", Id:\"210bdd5a0a0b13491f388b001bcb7a1add12a65706be7831f82c94d74424025d\", Status:0x0, Pid:\"init\", Timestamp:0x576844da}" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.036122814Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.036206299Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdin: end" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.036250871Z" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.036536700Z" level=debug msg="Closing buffered stdin pipe" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.045908932Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.23/containers/210bdd5a0a0b13491f388b001bcb7a1add12a65706be7831f82c94d74424025d/json" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.046328482Z" level=debug msg="Revoking external connectivity on endpoint pedantic_visvesvaraya (610b704780467ffa91695276c37bfc30d3e1c5b1a496ac2dda9021bcfdb6890c)" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.185521943Z" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint pedantic_visvesvaraya's interface on network bridge" 
time="2016-06-20T19:32:42.185699731Z" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.2)"
```

Comment: Are you using Boot2Docker? Could edit your question with the  `/var/log/docker.log` file contents? Regards.

Comment: You can copy it to a local dir by using `docker-machine scp default:/var/log/docker.log ./`

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto I think I am using Boot2Docker. I see it in the logs. I've also discovered that if I use "-it" the volume mount successfully, but upon exiting the docker container the I see the volume is no longer mounted. This works: docker run-it  -v /c/Users/myuser/documents/development:/home image/name`

Comment: I can't perceive anything wrong with your logs. I do noticed that you're trying to map the guest's /home directory to the host's `/c/Users/myuser/documents/development` dir. Thing is that /home is usually a root user owned directory in linux distros. Have you tried adding `--user=root` to your command?

Comment: by the way, is it ok to say which image you're trying to run? At least, what linux distro is it based on?

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto OK, thanks, yes, the image I'm using here is kaggle/python. I didn't think about how `/home` is root owned. I actually chose that directory arbitrarily. Is there a standard place to mount to in this kind of situation?

Comment: No restrictions, it's a guess, I was guessing that maybe the *nix user performing that mapping is not allowed to read that /home dir. But now that you've told me the image you're using and checking it's Dockerfile it seems unlikely.

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto All right well thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: There's a section in the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ entitled `Mount a host directory as a data volume` it says that docker-machine tools for Windows tries to auto-share c/Users with the virtual Boot2Docker system, could you check in VirtualBox configs if there's a shared directory called c/Users?

Comment: Yes, it's there and being shared with full access.